# How to cancel MBProgressHUD before finish in ios sdk

Tags: ios, iphone

In iOS SDK Possible to cancel MBProgressHUD before loading i ma MBProgressHUD for getting data from server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method
    `- (void)showAnimated:(BOOL)animated whileExecutingBlock:(dispatch_block_t)block;`, put you code about getting data from server in the block.

Comment: Thanks for replay. but i want to stop MBProgressHUD process before load. how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

refer `usage` in the docs for how to hide MBProgressHUD and refer the example given in the [MBProgressHUD library](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)